# Facebook comments in WordPress site getting deleted when post goes from Scheduled to Published

Tags: wordpress, facebook, plugins, comments

Basically what says in the title. I have a simple WordPress site to organize a community tournament.

Teams comment in the match event page (which is a Post) to fix a match time they both can play.

I chose to use Facebook Comments because notifications are shown in the players Facebook and they actually realize they have to organize the match.

But when the event (post) goes from Scheduled to Published comments just reset. Is like Facebook Comments assume is a new post and starts all over.

Any ideas?

Website: http://urudota.movinta.net/temporada-ii-grupo-b/

Comment: Does the URL of the post change when it goes from scheduled to publish?

Comment: No, URL stays the same.

Comment: For now the workaround was force the publish before the date arrives.